# Full URL from http.Request

Tags: go, goland

I need to return the full URL address of the server in the response to the request, what is the best way to do this?

```
func mainPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
    
       w.Write([]byte(r.Host + r.RequestURI))
   }
}
```

I don't understand how to add the protocol here (http:// or https://).

```
localhost:8080/ => http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: What about `r.URL`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. i used all methods from r.URL.

Comment: I mean, why don't you use `r.URL.String()` instead of `r.Host + r.RequestURI`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when You are starting a HTTP/s server You use either `ListenAndServe` or `ListenAndServeTLS` or both together on different ports.

If You are using just one of them, then from `Listen..` it's obvious which scheme request is using and You don't need a way to check and set it.

but if You are serving on both HTTP and HTTP/s then You can use `request.TLS` state. if its `nil` it means it's HTTP.

```
    // TLS allows HTTP servers and other software to record
    // information about the TLS connection on which the request
    // was received. This field is not filled in by ReadRequest.
    // The HTTP server in this package sets the field for
    // TLS-enabled connections before invoking a handler;
    // otherwise it leaves the field nil.
    // This field is ignored by the HTTP client.
    TLS *tls.ConnectionState
```

an example:

```golang
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    scheme := "http"
    if r.TLS != nil {
        scheme = "https"
    }
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v://%v%v", scheme, r.Host, r.RequestURI)))
}
```